# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 adds null character \u0000

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a strange situation happening when I create a new state. I've adapted the [comercial paper smart contract](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/commercial-paper/organization/digibank/contract/lib/papercontract.js), and I'm using the State and StateList abstractions.

I have simple chaincode to create an asset called log:

```
async createLog(ctx, loggerName, logId, ...) {
    //Check if client is a Logger

        let log = Log.createInstance(loggerName, logId, logOriginalTimestamp, idAudit, typeAuditID, auditText, auditUtilUPN, auditHostIP, processo, CuditMCcCdress);

        // Add the log to the list of all similar commercial papers in the ledger world state
        await ctx.LogList.addLog(log);


        ...
}
```

I create a composite key with loggerName and logId.

```
class Log extends State {

    constructor(obj) {
        super(Log.getClass(), [obj.loggerName, obj.logId]);
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
```

I add the logs with the command:

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --channelID mychannel --name logs -c '{"function":"org.Log:createLog", "Args":["1","1"]}' --waitForEvent
```

But apparently, Fabric adds a null character on the beginning of the key, which I can check on CouchDB:

```
{
 "id": "\u0000org.loglist\u0000\"1\"\u0000\"1\"\u0000",
 "key": "\u0000org.loglist\u0000\"1\"\u0000\"1\"\u0000",
 "value": {
  "rev": "1-c153101fc7cb0d5c363f893857ac221a"
 },
 "doc": {
  "_id": "\u0000org.loglist\u0000\"1\"\u0000\"1\"\u0000",
  "_rev": "1-c153101fc7cb0d5c363f893857ac221a",
...
  "key": "\"1\":\"1\"",
  "logId": "1",
...
  "~version": "CgMBAwA="
 }
}
```

When I'm querying the object, I get an error:

```
Error: first character of the key [org.Log"1""1"] contains a null character which is not allowed
```

Which makes sense, because effectively there are null characters in several places. Why?

Comment: I believe these are the composite key component delimiters, so splits the key into the composite key components.

Comment: I would have to use the query methods to get a state from a composite key, then? @david_k

Comment: That's one way to do it, I'm sure it would be possible to query couch directly and handle the returned information, it's just going via the chaincode query apis does it for you.